# Capacitor app keeps crashing on android device when i receive an fcm notification

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

My app is using firebase cloud messaging for notifications along with capacitor-community-fcm.

When I receive a notification i get a popup on my screen saying "Soogroo has stopped".

here's the logcat message when the app crashes.

```
2021-12-18 13:40:47.335 21155-21155/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.Soogroo.soogroo, PID: 21155

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.google.firebase.messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Soogroo.soogroo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Soogroo.soogroo-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3502)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1732)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Soogroo.soogroo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Soogroo.soogroo-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3499)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1732)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

It's saying it can't find the firebase class "com.google.firebase.messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService" but i dont know why that is.

heres my androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Soogroo.soogroo">

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:name="com.Soogroo.soogroo.MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_main" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>

<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
          </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

heres my app/build.gardle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Soogroo.soogroo"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
        ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
     def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
 } catch(Exception e) {
 logger.warn("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. 
 Push Notifications won't work")
 }
```

heres my root build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' 

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
   repositories {
         google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same exact issue.  Let me know if you figure out a solution.

Comment: are your MyFirebaseMessagingService built in kotlin file ? if so. try to convert as java file. I got same problem as yours and now working properly